# Cost for doujinshi in Comiket?

Tags: doujinshi, comiket

There is a con in Japan called Comiket. This con is held twice a year. There are like a hundred of circles/booths that sell their merchandise.

I wonder how much cost for the production of their fan-made manga and artbook/illustatrion book.

- The price for a doujinshi manga is around  $20 - $40 based on this [site](https://otakurepublic.com/product/tag_page.html?tags=468744&type=header_tab)
- The price for illustration book is around $15 - $50 based on this
  [site](https://otakurepublic.com/product/tag_page.html?tags=405&type=header_tab)

according that, how much the production cost ?

Comment: Apparently it costs about ¥9000 ($90) to register as a circle and get a table at Comiket. Everything else it going to depend a lot the actual participant.

Comment: The answer would depend on what kind of product you are trying to make. Registration cost is 9000¥ according to Ross. But for the production it would depend on what you make. A game? A manga book? Is the game voiced? Who are your co-workers? Are you hiring professionals? Or just amateurs, classmates? Transport also depends on where do you live. The further, the more expensive.

Comment: @AyaseEri, edited. Is this still too broad ?

Comment: I suspect given the nature of the product being sold, doujinshi, most circles are just hoping to break even on their direct production costs. It's a hobby, not something that pays the rent. I found some actual numbers, but note the profit and loss numbers are for an entire year, including sales and costs outside of Comiket: http://fanhackers.transformativeworks.org/2012/06/how-much-money-do-doujinshi-creators-actually-make-some-statistics-from-comiket/

Comment: @RossRidge i have added the price for each items

Comment: Those prices mostly reflect the cost of shipping things overseas from Japan. At Comiket, doujinshi publications are offered for sale at a much lower price, usually ¥300-¥600 ($3-$6) according to the article I linked.

Comment: Iam sorry i cant find a website that list price for a regular doujin  ini Japan